# Newtonsoft Json Convert does not convert json string to object

Tags: c#, json

I have these classes

```
public class ResponseEntryInfoAndTollDue
{
    public int Code { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public TagEntryInfo TagEntryInfo { get; set; }
    public TollMatrix TollMatrix { get; set; }
    public List<TagInfoParam> TagInfoParams { get; set; }
    public ResponseEntryInfoAndTollDue()
    {
        TagEntryInfo = new TagEntryInfo();
        TollMatrix = new TollMatrix();
        TagInfoParams = new List<TagInfoParam>();
    }
}

public class TagEntryInfo
{
    public long TrxnID { get; set; }
    public string TagRFIDNumber { get; set; }
    public string EntryTrxnDTime { get; set; }
    public int EntryPlaza { get; set; }
    public short EntryLane { get; set; }
    public string EntryDirection { get; set; }
    public string EntryLaneType { get; set; }
    public string PostingDateTime { get; set; }
    public string Action { get; set; }
}

public class TollMatrix
{
    public decimal TollDue { get; set; }
    public decimal TollVat { get; set; }
    public decimal TollNoVat { get; set; }
    public bool IsDefaulted { get; set; }
}

public class TagInfoParam
{
    public DateTime? AsOfDate { get; set; }
    public Decimal? AvailableBalance { get; set; }
    public string TagNumber { get; set; }
    public string PLateNumber { get; set; }
    public Int16 HonorPlate { get; set; }
    public Int16 TagStatusID { get; set; }
    public string TID { get; set; }
    public string EPC { get; set; }
    public string AccountTypeID { get; set; }
    public Int16 AccountStatusID { get; set; }
    public Int16 TagClassID { get; set; }
    public Int16 Status { get; set; }
}
```

From a webservice I get this json string:

```
{"Result":{"Code":0,"Message":"With entry info computed toll due","TagEntryInfo":{"TrxnID":6666750,"TagRFIDNumber":"1234567890","EntryTrxnDTime":"2021-01-16 16:40:16.560","EntryPlaza":123,"EntryLane":1,"EntryDirection":"B","EntryLaneType":"A","PostingDateTime":"2021-01-16T16:43:16.05","Action":"A"},"TollMatrix":{"TollDue":164.0000,"TollVat":17.5700,"TollNoVat":146.4300,"IsDefaulted":false},"TagInfoParams":[{"AsOfDate":"2021-01-16T17:12:04.213","AvailableBalance":537.0000,"TagNumber":"1234567890","PLateNumber":"Q123","HonorPlate":1,"TagStatusID":1,"TID":"Elfkajs98","EPC":"889080990709","AccountTypeID":"REV","AccountStatusID":1,"TagClassID":1,"Status":1}]},"Id":351,"Exception":null,"Status":5,"IsCanceled":false,"IsCompleted":true,"CreationOptions":0,"AsyncState":null,"IsFaulted":false}
```

This is how I convert it:
var response = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(ret);

I know that it doesn't get converted because this is what I get:

[image]

This is the result:

[image]

Why is this not being converted into an object?

Comment: @Fabio Sorry, I wasn't able to include it. Please see my edit.

Comment: How you verify that it is not deserialised? Did you get an exception?

Comment: Json string in the sample has "attribute" `Result`, but none of the types you provided has it.

Comment: @Fabio I don't get any exception. So should I create a Class Result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Fabio also mentioned that your json contains the attribute `Result` which is not part of your object so you can use below logic to deserialize

```
var jObj = JObject.Parse(json);
var responseEntryInfoAndTollDue = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ResponseEntryInfoAndTollDue>(jObj["Result"].ToString());
```

The above code first parse the Json to `JObject` and uses `Result` property to deserialize to `ResponseEntryInfoAndTollDue` object.

Check this fiddle - https://dotnetfiddle.net/7Pc3sJ